# Jasper multiaxis chart customized scaling

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a multiaxis chart bar char and line chart. My customizer class has following code snippet.

```
 @Override
    public void customize(final JFreeChart chart, final JRChart jasperChart) {

        final Plot plot = chart.getPlot();

        if (plot instanceof CategoryPlot) {
            final CategoryPlot cPlot = (CategoryPlot) plot;
            final ValueAxis axis = new NumberAxis();
            axis.setMinorTickMarksVisible(true);
            axis.setMinorTickCount(1);
            cPlot.setRangeAxis(axis);
        } else if (plot instanceof XYPlot) {
            final XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) plot;
            xyPlot.setRangeMinorGridlinesVisible(true);

        }

    }
```

The chart looks like

[image]

The scales are messed up and are not on the same line.

How can i fix this issue.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the above code to following and its all good

```
 @Override
    public void customize(final JFreeChart chart, final JRChart jasperChart) {

        final Plot plot = chart.getPlot();

        if (plot instanceof CategoryPlot) {
            final CategoryPlot cPlot = (CategoryPlot) plot;
            cPlot.getRangeAxis().setMinorTickCount(2);
            cPlot.getRangeAxis().setMinorTickMarksVisible(true);
        } else if (plot instanceof XYPlot) {
            final XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) plot;
            xyPlot.setRangeMinorGridlinesVisible(true);
            xyPlot.getRangeAxis().setMinorTickCount(2);
            xyPlot.getRangeAxis().setMinorTickMarksVisible(true);

        }

    }
```